# Trying to input text and values from excel into Python Lists

Tags: python, excel, list, openpyxl

This is my code:

```
for i in range(1, maxRows+1):
   nameContent = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1).value)
   nameList = []
   nameList.append(nameContent)
   print(nameList)
   rateContent = float(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).value)
   rateList = []
   rateList.append(rateContent)
   print(rateList)
   hoursContent = float(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 2).value)
   hoursList = []
   hoursList.append(hoursContent)
   print(hoursList)
```

When I print each list, it only print the most recent text/value. How do I keep all values/text in the list so I can work with the lists in later code?

Note: I am using the openpyxl module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redefining the list inside of the loop. This means at every iteration it resets the list to an empty list. Try to put the list definitions (`namelist = []`) outside of the loop.